# Error when linking C / Rust "Hello world": undefined reference to `std::io::stdio::_print

Tags: c, gcc, rust

I'd like to build and link the two files:

**hello.rs**

```
#![crate_type="staticlib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn print_hello() {
    println!("hello, world");
}
```

**hi.c**

```
extern void print_hello();

int main()
{
    print_hello();
}
```

Here are the commands I used and the error:

```
> rustc hello.rs --emit=obj
> gcc hi.c hello.o -o hi 
hello.o: In function `print_hello':
hello.0.rs:(.text.print_hello+0xa8): undefined reference to `std::io::stdio::_print::h3f2263e4b2c9891b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I include Rust's stdlib while linking those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear to me why the code specifies `#![crate_type="staticlib"]` and then the compilation goes out of its way to ignore that via `--emit=obj`. Compiling to a static library will include the necessary parts of the Rust standard library:

```
$ rustc hello.rs
note: link against the following native artifacts when linking against this static library
note: the order and any duplication can be significant on some platforms, and so may need to be preserved
note: library: System
note: library: c
note: library: m
$ gcc hi.c libhello.a -lSystem -lc -lm -o hi
$ ./hi
hello, world
```

This output is from macOS 10.12; check the appropriate libraries for your own system.

Note that you can also specify the crate type on the command line: `--crate-type staticlib`; it doesn't need to be in the source.

Comment: Ah! It looks that I might have either chosen wrong crate_type or unnecessarily used --emit=obj. Could the same work with --emit=obj if I used a different crate type?

Comment: @d33tah why do you wish to use `--emit=obj`?

Comment: Because I got used to this way of linking. But if it's non-trivial, I can link in a static library.